# Htaccess, urlrewriting and subdomain, how to had an exception?

Tags: .htaccess, exception, redirect

I am working on this website: 
www.montreuxjazz.com

There, we put a htaccess to rewrite the urls:

```
RewriteRule ^([^\/]*)/([^\/]*)$  index.php?pageid=$1&newsid=$2 [L]
```

Unfortunately, this htaccess avoid the access to http://newsletter.montreuxjazz.com/noel2011_en.html .

Do you know how to modifiy the htaccess so that everything which is on newsletter.montreuxjazz.com/ become accessible?

Thank you in advance for your help!
See you, 
David

Comment: Not sure how that rule affects access to that URL

Answer (score 0):

What about only processing your rule when it would otherwise take you to a nonexistent path?

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}  !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/])/([^/])$    index.php?pageid=$1&newsid=$2  [L]
```